# rails blank entry always appended to end of collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, collections, append

I am having an issue where there is always an extra blank added to my collection so it looks like someone left a blank comment. I found out that if I put the comment responses before the comment form, I don't have this issue. :

articles\show.html.erb

```
<p>
  <h2><%= @article.title %></h2>
</p>

<p>
  <%= @article.desc %>
</p>

<h4>Add a comment</h4>
<%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :commenter %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= @article.comments.count %> (shows 0)

<h2>Comments</h2>
<% @article.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <% next if comment.blank? %>
  <p>
    <strong>Commenter:</strong>
    <%= comment.body %>
  </p>
 <% end %>
```

The result is always something like (even when no comment is posted):

Commenter:

Comments controller

```
...
def create
    @article = article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comment.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to question_path(@article)
end
...
```

Articles controller 'show'

```
  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Why is a blank "commenter:" always being rendered when I put the form before the comments?

Comment: Probably because there is an empty comment?

Comment: Share your controller's action, and in rails console, look for any empty comments in your table

Comment: I checked the db using sql lite manager and there are no comment records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you called `@article.comments.build` before you listing the comments, a *'blank'* comment is created. But this comment is not a blank object, so `comment.blank?` doesn't work. You can just modify your condition to solve this problem:

Change

`<% next if comment.blank? %>`

To

`<% next if comment.persisted? %>`

Comment: i ended up using <% if comment.persisted? %>